# increase speed on "bouncing" object

Tags: javascript

I don't know a lot about JS, but i have to do assignments with it. right now i have a ball that bounces from one side of the screen to the other. with every bounce the colour of the screen and the ball change. but i'd like a slight increase of speed with every bounce as well(or a random speed every time it bounces if that's easier). this is the code I have for moving, the bouncing and the colour changing now:

```
    fill(r,g,b);
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, circleSize, circleSize);

    circleX += moveX;

    if (circleX > width - circleSize / 2 || circleX < circleSize / 2) {
            moveX = -moveX;
            r = random(255);
            g = random(255);
            b = random(255);
        }
```

moveX is always 5 now and changes to -5 when turning back. but i'd like it if it turned into -6 and then +7 when going forward again. or something like that at least.
I thank you guys in advance for helping me and please explain it like you're explaining it to a child.

Comment: Right now you take the value moveX and just add a negative sign in front of it, and the other way around. You can just add a -1 to the -moveX (like -moveX -1), assuming you're going to loop, it'll increase the speed with every turn that it takes when moving back. If you want to increase it at both turns, add one "+1" at line 4, and one "-1" at line 7.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add additional details to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add another test inside your collision detection code to increase the speed. If the velocity is positive, then you want to add 1. If the velocity is negative, you want to subtract 1. Your code would look something like this...

```js
...
moveX = -moveX
if (moveX < 0) {
  --moveX;
} else {
  ++moveX;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, lets make a function which takes a number and returns `+1` for non-negative numbers (positive or `0`) and `-1` for negative numbers, i.e. it's *sign*

```
function sign(x) {
    if (x < 0) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

---

A full implementation of `sign` would have a special case for `0`, and is [available natively in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)

---

Next, when it becomes time to change `moveX` separate it's magnitude (absolute value) and sign, increment it's magnitude and put the two pieces back together again before flipping the sign over

```
moveX = -sign(moveX) * (Math.abs(moveX) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many times the circle has "bounced" and add it to the speed.

```
var base_speed = 5;
var bounces = 0;
var direction = 1; //positive for moving right, negative for moving left
var moveX = base_speed + bounces * direction;

circleX += moveX;

if (circleX > width - circleSize / 2 || circleX < circleSize / 2) {
    direction = -direction;
    bounces++;
    r = random(255);
    g = random(255);
    b = random(255);
}
```